# A result, or part of the definition of spanning? $\mathcal{A}\subset \langle \mathcal{A}\rangle$

Tags: linear-algebra, logic, vector-spaces

I am paraphrasing the definition of *spanning* given in Linear Algebra and Matrix Theory, 2nd Ed., by Ever D. Nering.

**The set of all linear combinations of elements of any $\mathcal{A}\supset \mathcal{V}$ is called the set *spanned* by $\mathcal{A}$, and denoted by $\langle \mathcal{A}\rangle$.  "It is part of this definition that $\mathcal{A}\subset \langle \mathcal{A}\rangle$."**

The last part is a direct quote.  It seems to me that $\mathcal{A}\subset \langle \mathcal{A}\rangle$ should be given as a result, rather than as part of the definition.  Is there a reason not to consider it a logical consequence of the first part of the definition?

Comment: Well, formally it is a result, although a trivial one. The author is pretty much saying "It immediately follows from the definition that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \left< \mathcal{A} \right>$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the author is confusing two common and equivalent definitions of $\langle\mathcal A\rangle$:

> $\langle\mathcal A\rangle$ is the set of all linear combinations of elements of $\mathcal A$.

and

> $\langle\mathcal A\rangle$ is the smallest subspace of $V$ that is a superset of $\mathcal A$.

In the second of these cases it is indeed part of the definition that $
\mathcal A \subseteq \langle\mathcal A\rangle$. In the first it is an easy *consequence* of the definition (every vector in $\mathcal A$ is a linear combination of *itself* with coefficient $1$), but not literally part of it.

(The second of the definitions is of course only a definition once we prove that there is a unique smallest such subspace -- but that isn't hard either).

Comment: I am vaguely familiar with the second usage from group theory.  I will have to leave that for another day.  I'm trying to shore up my linear algebra to help me understand Edwards's Advance Calculus of Several Variables which I am studying to shore up the skills necessary form mastering analytical dynamics and differential geometry which are needed for general relativity and quantum mechanics.  Thanks for the guidance.  It was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it follows from the definition, as the author probably means. If we have a set $A = \{a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n\}$, it is obvious that $\{1*a_1, \dots, 1*a_n\} = A \subset \langle A \rangle$, because we can write the elements of A as trivial linear combinations, as demonstrated.